# install ubuntu on dell xps 8500 with preinstalled windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, uefi, secure-boot

I got a Dell xps 8500 pre-installed window 8. I installed ubuntu 12.10 and after reboot the system directly enter into ubuntu. I use boot-repair and I got the grub menu with ubuntu and windows 8. If I enter Ubuntu, there is no problem. But if I enter Windows 8 it is ok for the first time, but if I restart the system, I got a line "No bootable device available!!! Press any key to retry." on the top of the screen.

In the bios I open the UEFI and secure boot.

This is the boot info: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1611189/.

What can I do now?

2013-02-07
Thanks Rod Smith very much for his great help. I summarize here my problem and the solution:

1. Platform: Dell xps 8500, 1T hdd, pre-installed Windows 8; UEFI open, secure boot open
2. Problem: Install Ubuntu 12.10 (I want to use 10.04, but because only from 12.10 UEFI and secure boot is supported), everything is ok except entering Windows 8 and restart. The system will not find boot device. The reason here is a 'windows boot manager' that revise the boot file.
3. Solution: in Command Shell type: "bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi" to correct the bootfile. The "shimx64.efi" file is under "/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/". (As Rod said we should choose shimx64.efi since I open secure boot option; this also can be found after using 'boot-repair' which says: "Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!"; so if your system is different check there.)
4. Note: as before the solution I have tried with Rod's advice to kill "fast boot" and "hybrid boot" options. I didn't test if I change back to "fast boot" will have problem. Anyway, this can be tested since now the system works fine.

Comment: I tried "powercfg -h off" under Windows 8 doesn't help. I power off with the button under Window 8, and then power on the system, ubuntu is gone.

Comment: I think windows 8 change the uefi when it starts. I check my BIOS, when there is a boot option as "UEFI:ubuntu", then ubuntu can be started. And when the option is "UEFI:windows boot manager", then Windows can be started once, i.e., after reboot from that the "no bootable device" will emerge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but my suspicion is that you're running into problems because of a Windows feature called "fast boot" or "hybrid boot." This system basically involves a suspend-to-disk rather than a shutdown. This is known to cause problems on dual-boot systems, and IIRC, it can even corrupt the EFI System Partition (ESP), which can lead to the symptoms you report. A quick Google turned up some sites with instructions on shutting off this feature:

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html

http://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3152/~/disable-windows-8-fast-startup-%28hibernate-file%29

Note that I don't have a Windows 8 installation, so I can't offer any firsthand advice about this; I'm just passing on what I've read elsewhere.

---

Edit: If Windows is "taking over" the boot process, you can fix the problem by using the Windows `bcdedit` command:

1. Boot Windows.
2. Launch a Command Shell prompt with Administrator privileges. (You do this by right-clicking the shell icon and selecting the option to "Run as Administrator.")
3. Type `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` to register GRUB as the desired default boot program. (Note, however, that if you haven't disabled Secure Boot, you may need to specify `shim.efi` instead of `grubx64.efi`. If you're using something other than GRUB, or if it's not in the specified location, you'll need to adjust the command appropriately.) Note that `{bootmgr}` should be typed exactly that way, including the curly braces; that's not an attempt to denote a variable.

Thereafter, Windows *should* settle down and stop disabling GRUB as the default boot program.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I check off all the fast boot things. Still the same. This time I tried firstly shutdown (not restart), then I get back to windows (Ubuntu disappeared). Then I restart, the same things. I googled with "windows 8 restart", and do "bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes", no help.

Comment: Someone said about the bios. Anyway my pc has just arrived no more than one month. Still I checked Dell for xps8500, it is A09 (12092012), while my pc is A09 (09052012). And in the CMOS, the boot device will change between (UEFI:ubuntu) and (UEFI:windows boot manager). I suspect when I enter windows 8, windows boot manager does something to change the EFI files.

Comment: Please see my edit/additional information.